# remove leading zero from column with out any while loop in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a accountNo column varchar(50)

sample data

```
000qw33356
034453534u
a56465470h
00000000a1
```

I need output  like..

```
qw33356
34453534u
a56465470h
a1
```

I have limitation that i can not use while loop in side UDF as this is creating performance issue .

Comment: Did you already try something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data doesn't contains spaces you can use:

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(data, '0', ' ')),' ', '0')
```

If there are spaces, you could replace them first to something else that doesn't exist and then replace back at the end.

Comment: What happens when one of the value has already one space for example 'a564654 70h'

Comment: @StackNewUser Like I said, in that case the space should be first replaced to something else and then back to space in the end. Otherwise it gets translated into 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat cute variant that doesn't need a replacement character (although that's the one I'd usually use):

```
declare @t table (Val varchar(20))
insert into @t(Val) values
('000qw33356'),
('034453534u'),
('a56465470h'),
('00000000a1')

select SUBSTRING(Val,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',Val),9000)
from @t
```

Results:

```
--------------------
qw33356
34453534u
a56465470h
a1
```

Basically, we just take a substring from the first non-`0` character to the end (assuming 9000 is larger than your input string length)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to find fist not zero character. And then get a SUBSTRING from this point to the end of a string:

```
SUBSTRING(accountNo, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',accountNo),1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Test VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('000qw33356')
,('034453534u')
,('a56465470h')
,('00000000a1');

SELECT SUBSTRING(Test,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',Test),1000)
FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PATINDEX**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(Data VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('000qw33356'),
('034453534u'),
('a56465470h'),
('00000000a1')

SELECT SUBSTRING(Data,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',Data),8000)
FROM @table
```

Comment: valex, Damien_the_unbeliever and me, we have posted exactly the same suggestion in the same minute (almost). Why are you repeating this answer 30 minutes later?